# ratio test on series with logarithms $\frac{n}{\log_{10}(n+1)}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

How do I correctly use the ratio test on series with logarithms to test for convergence?

For example, I have this series:

$$\frac{n}{\log_{10}(n+1)}$$

When I use this part of the ratio test: $a_{n+1}$

Do I re-arrange the series like so:

$$\frac{n+1}{\log_{10}(n+1+1)}$$
Or is there a different way of doing it. Also, can the logarithm be converted into series form, and how would it look like?

Comment: *Where* is there a series in your question?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: I mean that you talk about series but I don't see a single series in your question.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Apologies, I've been working with rather old books so they miss out on the sigma and limit notations. Hence, I sometimes forget to use them

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confused about the ratio test. What the ratio test says is this:

If $(a_n)$ is a sequence of real numbers, then

1. If $\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|}<1$, then the series $\sum_na_n$ converges absolutely.

2. If $\liminf_{n\to\infty}\frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|}>1$, then the series $\sum_na_n$ diverges.

Note that the inequalities **have to be strict.**

I assume you want to check whether the series $\sum_n\frac{n}{\log(n+1)}$ converges or diverges. You do not have to use the ratio test here, because $\frac{n}{\log(n+1)}\to\infty$, and it is well known that if $\sum_na_n$ converges then $|a_n|\to0$. So your series diverges for trivial reasons.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Suppose, what test is best to use when logarithms are involved for convergence or divergence?

Comment: @Workaroundcode There isn't such a thing as the best test I'm afraid :)

Comment: besides the best test, if you have the time may you show me a simple derivation of a series with logarithms to test for divergence or convergence?